# Unknown stickers with silver lines on black 2x4 tiles

Tags: set-identification, sticker-identification

I found two stickers in a bundle that I can't link to any set.

[image: 2 stickers on black plates]

Do you know which sets they may belong to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
[image]

Comes from Set #*[76047](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76047-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)* Black Panther Pursuit.